# Prevent a checkbox from being checked (not simply uncheck)

Tags: c#, checkbox

Under certain conditions a `checkbox` I have will display an error. I'm trying do disable the `checkbox` unless certain conditions are met.

I've tried the following

```
    private void checkBox66_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView3.RowCount == 0)
        {
            checkBox66.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

But I realized this actively checks the box, before realizing any kind of uncheck. I need to make sure the `checkbox` ignores any clicks on it while the rowcount is 0

Comment: Then use this code in `Form_Load` and where `dataGridView3.RowCount` can change.

Comment: Did you actually disable the checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Enabled` property to `false`. Whatever value the CheckBox has, checked or unchecked, will be unchangeable by the user. You can do this in the CheckBox's properties in the designer, or in code:

```
CheckBox1.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to prevent the checkbox from ***ever*** being checked if the rowcount = 0?

You could add code to the datagridview's RowsAdded and RowsRemoved events, enabling/disabling+unchecking the checkbox depending on the number of rows.

If the user requires an explanation for why the checkbox is disabled, you could put a label next to the checkbox.